MissingPluginException in Flutter with tflite
I am trying to use the tflite package in my Flutter app, but I am encountering a MissingPluginException when attempting to load a model. Here are the details:
Flutter Version:

Flutter 3.24.4

Dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  tflite: ^1.1.2

Code:
Future<void> loadModel() async {
  try {
    var resultant = await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/model.tflite",
    );
    print("Result after loading model: $resultant");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error loading model: $e");
  }
}

Error:
Error loading model: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite)

What I Have Tried:

Ensured that all dependencies are correctly installed.

Restarted the application multiple times. Already tried flutter clean.

Verified the asset path for the model file.

I am using the latest version of the plugin.


Environment:

OS: Windows

Android Emulator: sdk gphone16k x86 64


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

tflite package was not updated since 3 years ago, this error probably because the package is not compatible with the current flutter version. Try tflite_flutter package instead, it was released 55 days ago.
